# How do I encode a PHP array to a JSON array, not object?

Tags: php, zend-framework, json

I am trying to json_encode an array which is returned from a Zend_DB query.

var_dump gives: (Manually adding 0 member does not change the picture.)

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["comment_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["erasable"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(6) "test 1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["comment_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["erasable"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(6) "test 1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["comment_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["erasable"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(6) "jhghjg"
  }
}
```

The encoded string looks like:

```
{"1":{"comment_id":"1","erasable":"1","comment":"test 1"},
 "2":{"comment_id":"2","erasable":"1","comment":"test 1"},
 "3":{"comment_id":"3","erasable":"1","comment":"jhghjg"}}
```

What I need is:

```
[{"comment_id":"1","erasable":"1","comment":"test 1"},
{"comment_id":"2","erasable":"1","comment":"test 1"},
{"comment_id":"3","erasable":"1","comment":"jhghjg"}]
```

Which is what the php.ini/json_encode documentation says it should look like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How are you setting up your initial array?

If you set it up like:

```
array(
 "1" => array(...),
 "2" => array(...),
);
```

then you don't have an array with numeric indexes but strings, and that's converted to an object in JS world. This can happen also if you don't set a strict order (i.e. starting at 0 instead of 1).

This is a shot in the dark, however, because I can't see your original code: try setting your array without using keys at all in the first place:

```
array(
 array(...),
 array(...),
);
```

Comment: +1 # an array not starting with 0 for its key isn't an array. phps fault though for having a weird bastard lovechild of array/hash that works properly as neither.

Comment: Like I said, that doesn't make it an array, that makes it a hash with a numeric key, which just *happens* in this case to be close to 0 at the start  because thats what the data in the database has.

Comment: Translation: what you want is logically impossible.

Comment: +1 to Kent... wish I could upvote your comments... instead, I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @Kent, I also can't stand that PHP treats hashes and arrays as the same thing. That's also been the reason for many people using `map = new Array(); map.prop = 'blah'` in JS. They are not the same!

Answer (score 6):

Added information that expands on [Seb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684262/encode-array-to-json-in-php-to-get-elm1-elm2-elm3-instead-of-elm1-elm2-e/684299#684299)'s answer.

```
php > print json_encode( array( 'a', 'b', 'c' ) ) ;
["a","b","c"]
php > print json_encode( array( 0 => 'a',  1 => 'b', 2 => 'c' ) ) ;
["a","b","c"]
php > print json_encode( array( 1 => 'a',  2 => 'b', 3 => 'c' ) ) ;
{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}
php >
```

Note: its formatting it this way with good cause:

If you were to send

```
{"1":"a","2":"b","3":"c"}
```

as

```
["a","b","c"]
```

When you did  `$data[1]`   in Php you would get back "a", but on the JavaScript side, you would get back "b" .

Answer (score 2):

A common way to test for a traditional, continuous array in php is to check for an index '0'.  Try adding that to your array, it'll probably considering it an array instead of hashmap.

Answer (score -3):

i had a similar problem, got it to work after adding '' (single quotes) around the json_encode string.
Following from my js file:

```
var myJsVar =  <?php echo json_encode($var); ?> ;    -------> NOT WORKING  
var myJsVar = '<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>' ;   -------> WORKING
```

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. It will expand to `var myJsVar = '{"1":"a"....}'` which is a *string*, not an array. You'll have to decode it somehow in JS Land to make it usable, either by handing it off to a proper JSON parser or doing `myJsVar = eval(myJsVar`) somewhere later.