# how to get length of json encoded array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json encoded array like this:

```
{
  "ar0":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9939202,\"lng\":72.50009499999999},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"waypoints\":[[23.0316834,72.4779436]]}",

  "ar1":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0420584,\"lng\":72.67145549999998},\"waypoints\":[[23.02237,72.6500747]]}",

  "ar2":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"end\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"waypoints\":[[23.0016629,72.58898380000005]]}"

 }
```

my quetion is :

(1) How to find length of this array? `//here it is 3`

(2) How to use it's value?
`//for example:for as0 the value is {\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9939202,\"lng\":72.50009499999999},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"waypoints\":[[23.0316834,72.4779436]]}`

`javascript code where i use upper things :`

```
 function setroute(os)
{
    var wp = [];
    for(var i=0;i<os.waypoints.length;i++)
        wp[i] = {'location': new google.maps.LatLng(os.waypoints[i][0], os.waypoints[i][1]),'stopover':false }

    ser.route({'origin':new google.maps.LatLng(os.start.lat,os.start.lng),
    'destination':new google.maps.LatLng(os.end.lat,os.end.lng),
    'waypoints': wp,
    'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},function(res,sts) {
        if(sts=='OK')ren.setDirections(res);
    })  
}

function fetchdata()
{
    var jax = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    jax.open('POST','process.php');
    jax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    jax.send('command=fetch')
    jax.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(jax.readyState==4) {                
    alert(JSON.parse(jax.responseText).ar0);
        try {
                console.log(jax.responseText);

          //it is not work

        for(var i=0;i<JSON.parse(jax.responseText).length;i++) 
                {
                  setroute( eval('(' + jax.responseText + ')') );
                }
            }
        catch(e){ alert(e); }
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your JSON is not an array, but an object. If you want it to be an array, it should be something like this:

```
[
  "{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9939202,\"lng\":72.50009499999999},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"waypoints\":[[23.0316834,72.4779436]]}",

  "{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0420584,\"lng\":72.67145549999998},\"waypoints\":[[23.02237,72.6500747]]}",

  "{\"start\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"end\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"waypoints\":[[23.0016629,72.58898380000005]]}"

 ]
```

Then, you can get a javascript array as follows:

```
var array = JSON.parse(jax.responseText);
```

And access values as follows:

```
array[0]

array.length
```

---

**EDIT:** In order to have a real JSON array with the PHP `json_encode` method, see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/684314/1292605).

With this modification you will be able to use all the possibilities of JS array without workaround.

Comment: this is not an answer.i create json encode array in php and use it in javascript.

Comment: I didn't know that you used PHP. I updated my answer, I hope that will help you more ;)

Answer (score 5):

Objects in JavaScript don't have a `.length` property like Arrays do.

In ES5 you can do: `Object.keys({}).length; // 0`

The other solution would be to loop over all the properties of your object with a `for .. in` loop and count.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code. It will produce your desired output 3

```
var test = {
  "ar0":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9939202,\"lng\":72.50009499999999},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"waypoints\":[[23.0316834,72.4779436]]}",

  "ar1":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"end\":{\"lat\":23.0420584,\"lng\":72.67145549999998},\"waypoints\":[[23.02237,72.6500747]]}",

  "ar2":"{\"start\":{\"lat\":23.0394491,\"lng\":72.51248850000002},\"end\":{\"lat\":22.9999061,\"lng\":72.65318300000001},\"waypoints\":[[23.0016629,72.58898380000005]]}"

 } 
 var getLength = function(obj) {
    var i = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            i++;
        }
    }
    return i;
};
 console.log(getLength(test));
```

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, you should use `Object.keys(item).length`

To get the values of your object, you should iterate over it with a `for` loop:

`for(var key in item)
{
  var val = item[key];
}`

Answer (score 2):

```
var count = 0;
Object.keys(json).forEach(function (key) {
    count++;
    alert(json[key].start.lat);
});

alert(count);
```

Using jQuery

```
$(json).each(function() { count++; alert(this.start.lat); }); 
alert(count);
```