# Database string value to PHP array to be used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-visualization

I need to store values into a Wordpress database and the use the value in a Google Chart.

The questions are:
1. What format do I use to store it into the database?
Currently I am using WP-TYPES and adding the array as follows to a Multi Line Box:

```
['Month','Value 1','Value 2'],['2004',1000,400],['2005',1170,460],['2006',660,1120],['2007',1030,540]
```

This is what it needs to output in the Javascript for the chart.

1. Convert the String to a array in PHP (Not doing it correctly)
   I retrieve the data with:

`$graphdata = types_render_field("graph-data", array("output" => "raw","separator"=>";"));`

This gives me a string value.

Then I add it to an array:
   `$thechartcontent[$i] = [
        "name" => get_the_title(),
        "chartheaders" => array($graphdata),
    ];`

1. In JavaScipt:
   I set the PHP Array to Java

   `var chart1 = <?php echo json_encode($thechartcontent[0]); ?>;`

Then I get the data from the array to a var:

```
 var chartheaders1 = chart1['chartheaders'];
```

This is where I get stuck. The value that I get is a string. It needs to show exactly this:

```
['Month','Value 1','Value 2'],['2004',1000,400],['2005',1170,460],['2006',660,1120],['2007',1030,540]
```

for it to work.

Any help please.

Comment: Did you try in JSON format?

Comment: I have yes. Tried json_decode, explode and serialize

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will not be exacly like you want since it's JSON encoded in JSON format. [This might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684262/how-do-i-encode-a-php-array-to-a-json-array-not-object). Or you can convert object into array in JS.

Comment: How can I get it exactly like that though. Otherwise the charts don't work. Should I store it in a different format maybe?

Comment: If you don't want to change format to force json_encode to encode as array, try converting Object to Array in JS. For example with jQuery.makeArray()

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are outputting is an array containing a string, which is not what you want.  You must split `$graphdata` into an array of arrays containing your data before adding it to `$thechartcontent`:

```
$graphdata = substr($graphdata, 1, strlen($graphdata) - 1); // trim the opening and closing brackets
$graphdata = explode('],[', $graphdata); // split $graphdata into an array of strings
foreach($graphdata as &$row) {
    $row = explode(',', $row); // split the row into an array
}
$thechartcontent[$i] = array(
    'name' => get_the_title(),
    'chartheaders' => $graphdata
);
```

When you json encode the data, you should use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` constant, so your numbers don't get quoted as strings:

```
var chart1 = <?php echo json_encode($thechartcontent[0], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
```